# Centering figure but not caption

Tags: floats, revtex

I would like to center an image but keep the caption aligned with the margins ( not centered).
When using [H] (here precisely):

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figures/mass.png}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er werihwer ierh eriher ih }
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
```

I get:
[image]

The caption is the way I want it, but the image is to the side.

If I add the following command:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figures/mass.png}}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er werihwer ierh eriher ih }
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
```

I get a centered image and the caption where I wish:
[image]

However, I don't want to use [H], I want to use [h]/[ht]/[htbp!]. If I change that, for example:

```
\begin{figure} [htbp!]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figures/mass.png}}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er werihwer ierh eriher ih }
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
```

I get:
[image]

Then the image is centered, but also the caption, and this is not what I want.

This what in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
```

please provide a simple solution.

cheers

Comment: `\begin{figure}[htbp] \centering \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a} \caption{Some really long caption here.} \end{figure}`?

Comment: @Troy u get the same thing, it centers the caption as well, this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Are you running any other packages? The caption is left aligned for me.

Comment: @Troy, I've added my preamble in the end of the question in case u find somthing

Comment: \centering should have no affect on the \caption (which is already \textwidth wide),  The \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off} will not center short captions either.

Comment: @jarhead, if you will publish article where rectex4-1 is house `documentclass`, than don't change anything. They require such layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\centerline` -- use `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,demo]{revtex4-1} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{float,graphicx}
% removed all other packages
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figures/mass.png}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er werihwer ierh eriher ih }
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP drew my attention to the fact that `[htbp]` should be used, rather than `[H]`. The `caption` package is known to be incompatible with the `revtex4-1` document class. Therefore, the best suggestion I can make is that you *not* load the `caption` package at all. If the text of the caption simply has to typeset in footnote size -- and I can't think of a good reason for this, since you're presumably using the `revtex4-1` document for some good reason -- you could place a `\footnotesize` directive at the start of the argument of the `\caption` instruction.

Comment: Again, it works with [H], but not with [htbp!], so what u suggest has not solved the problem

Comment: @jarhead - Ah, I had completely missed the part, toward the end of your posting, about not actually wanting `[H]` and, instead, wanting `[htbp!]`. The `caption` package is known to have some conflicts with the `revtex4-1` document class. I have to suggest that you *not* load the caption package. If you absolutely, positively *must* have the text in the caption typeset in footnotesize, all would suggest you start the argument of `\caption` with a `\footnotesize` directive.

Comment: @jarhead - I've posted an addendum to "formalize" my comments.

Comment: @Mico Not really “some conflicts”: it's simply incompatible.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks -- I've edited the sentence in question.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, revtex-4 automatically turns centering on inside floats (note: `[H]` is not implemented using `\@float`).

I also discovered a bug of sorts in caption.  Specifically, the `justification=justified` option does nothing, and therefore will not correct previous settings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}

\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,justification=justified}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [htbp!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figures/mass.png}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er werihwer ierh eriher ih}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The `justification=justified` option of the `caption package does work with other document classes -- but not with `revtex4-1`. Not clear whether that's a "bug" in the `caption` package or a plain-old incompatibility with the `revtex4-1` document class.

Comment: @Micro - Hence the "of sorts".  Interestingly, resetting \parfillskip etc. before caption doesn't work, nor has \caption been replaced by some other macro.

Comment: FWIW, my userid is "Mico", not "Micro". But then, Marco Daniel has had to get used to being called "Macro"...

Comment: @Mico - I finally figure it out: revtec4-1 modifies the definition of \parbox to center the text.

Answer (score 0):

The `caption` package is not compatible with `revtex4-1`:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Since the class is intended for submissions to some journals, authors should not tamper with its setting: it's the copy editors' job to make the document up for publication and your changes will just annoy them and possibly cause rejection.

In particular, besides `caption`, also `placeins` and `geometry` should not be loaded. If you need subfloats, the package of choice is

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

Just do

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{figures/mass.png}
\caption{The ordered and blac aldl dsjfd f eheher erhrhr erher
  rher h er h wer werh erher er rher erh  erh erhr erh er erherw
  werh rh erh  h werrfhwerhwer erioer ier ier ierw werui weriu
  weriufieruirehweriheih wei i i i eri uire rhh rh erh er
  werihwer ierh eriher ih}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
```

(choose whatever value you prefer for the width, but it would be better to have a PNG without scaling, because this will insert artifacts). The figure will be automatically centered.